# find command locking the system out

Tags: linux, bash, find

I had a folder , with 4+ million files in it. I managed to delete all files , in course of a week , using "find . -delete" and "kill -9" after a minute as it locks the system otherwise.

now the folder is empty. When i go to that folder and do "ls" , all is fine. I just see that the folder is empty.

But when i do "find foo/" , it locks the system again , just like the time when i used to delete those millions of files.

What can be the reason ?

Comment: The directory is probably huge, even though it doesn't contain any entries. Why `ls` is fast and `find` is not, however, is a mystery to me. Anyway it may be advisable to delete and recreate the directory so that it's small again.

Comment: Are there any dot files or dirs? `ls -a foo`

Comment: @Cyrus no. there is only . and .. , as expected

Comment: I would take a look at dmesg, because such long disk operations are usually caused by faulty disks.

Comment: @wurtel the directory was huge yeah , it head 89 mb of metadata even 1-2 weeks after all the delete process. There is anotehr file that i create and delete around 30.000 files every day , and it has a meta data of 2.9 mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer by sharing this question on Google Plus. The answer by [Axel Engeland](https://plus.google.com/+AxelEngeland):

> That really depends on the file system used. Directories are supposed
>   to store inode tables. If inode tables grow too large, another one is
>   created and the tables are linked. So even if you removed all the
>   files, there may still be a big amout of interlinked inode tables. if
>   you rmdir and mkdir the directory again, performance should be better.
>
> As you may have deleted all files but the last, the inode tables are
>   still in place. ls -ld foo should show you the size of directory meta
>   information. Consider:
>
> ```
> # mkdir some_dir
> # ls -ld some_dir
> drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 14 21:16 some_dir
> ```
>
> So, the directory has 4096 bytes for meta data. ok. Let's make some
>   files.
>
> ```
> # pushd some_dir ; for i in {1..1000} ; do mktemp test.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX ; done ; popd
> ```
>
> We just created 1000 files in some_dir.
>
> ```
> # ls -ld some_dir
> drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 49152 Oct 14 21:16 some_dir
> ```
>
> Oh wow, the directory now needs 49k für meta data. Let's remove the
>   files.
>
> ```
> # find some_dir/ -type f -delete
> # ls -ld some_dir
> drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 49152 Oct 14 21:19 some_dir
> ```
>
> The files are gone. But still 48k meta data. A find will still have to
>   go through all the meta data in the directory to... well... find
>   something.

Comment: This still doesn't explain why find is slower than ls

Comment: @artistoex How come ? find is slower because it is going through the inode metadata of the folder , which is huge , even if the folder is emptied

Comment: I don't think so. I've just skimmed over the gnu find and ls sources, and it basically does the same as ls does: `opendir()` followed by `readdir()` (see function xsavedir() in savedirinfo.c)

Comment: Besides that, even a couple of Million bytes of inode processing barely explain a weeks worth of computation.

Comment: there is no "a week worth of computation" . There is me "find . -delete" ing like 50k files in a minute and killing the process , whenever i find the server load low enough , in course of a week .

Comment: Okay, but anyway, what makes you think, find somehow goes over the whole inode data?  In what sense, anyway?  After all it's the kernels job to do that, and it does it anyway, even when `ls` is successively readdir()-ing the directory. So honestly, it is not at all clear what "going through the inode metadata" even means.

Answer (score 2):

Your file system may have some corruption on it.  Try running `fsck -f` over it (when it is unmounted), see if it finds any problems.

Comment: it's all about the huge amount of metadata of the folder as it seems

Answer (score 1):

Curious why you didn't just delete the whole directory and then recreate it:

```
rm -rf foo_dir
mkdir foo_dir
```

Or delete the files without using find:

```
cd [path]/foo_dir
rm -rf *
```

Perhaps deleting and recreating the directory would still help you.

Comment: the * expansion , thus the "rm -rf *" or "rm -rf foo/" doesn't work when you have 4 million of files in a folder

Comment: Some more detailed information: 
When you do a `rm -rf *` the shell will see the asterix (`*`) and feed it to rm.  In effect you do not start an `rm -rf *` but `rm -rf file1 file2 file3 file4 ...`. This runs into problems when there is not enough space in buffers to list all those expanded filenames.  Hence find with -delete or find with -exec {} +